# how to map result to right properties object using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have problem counting unique value in data base I have user table with status the status are Unknown = 0,In = 1,Out = 2,UnknownWasIn = 3,UnknownWasOut = 4, the problem are I don't have lookup table for this value in database becouse of that we have hard coded it. I have create class `StatusCounter`

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;

public  class StatusCounter
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int In { get; set; }
    public int Out { get;set ; }
    public int Unknow { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

just want to ask how can I map value to the right properties using linq

```
var result  =  from people in TBL_People 
               where people.Deleted == false
               group people by people.Status into s
               select new StatusCounter
```

TBLPeople

```
    public partial class TBLPeople 
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Status { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do one big group so you can do the individual counts.  Not sure if there is a more elegant way to do that other than just grouping by a constant.

```
var result  =  
    from people in TBL_People 
    where people.Deleted == false
    group people by 1 into s
    select new StatusCounter
    { 
        Total = s.Count(), 
        In = s.Count(p => p.Status == 1),
        Out = s.Count(p => p.Status == 2),
        Unknown = s.Count(p => p.Status == 3 || p.Status == 4),
        LastUpdatedDateTime = DateTime.Now
    }
```

I'm not sure what you want to set `LastUpdatedDateTime` to since the people table doesn't have a date column.

Comment: thanks for LastUpdatedDateTime  it will be the last updated time when the information get  from database ?

Comment: @user3277743 If I'm understanding you correctly then just `LastUpdatedDateTime  = DateTime.Now`?